# Keeping the edited item selected in a QListView

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

I have implemented a custom `QAbstractListModel` that is displayed in an editable `QListView`. The items in the model must be sorted, so the model implements the `sort()` method, and calls it from `setData()` after the data is stored.

The current behavior is that the user edits an item, the model is sorted, and the `QListView` is updated. But the selection remains on the item at the index where the edit happened. Instead, I would like the selection to move to the new index of the edited item.

How can I have the selection move with the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a way to achieve that. It is as simple as connecting to the `dataChanged(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)` signal of the model and updating the selection in the handler. My error was that I called the signal in `setData()` *before* sorting the model.

Instead, the model must be sorted first, then the new index of the modified item can be found, and finally, the `dataChanged(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)` signal must be called *with the new index*.